# pygame don't recognize the correct rect of my image

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

at Pygame I have a game with a background(at the code the image named:'bg) and an image on that(named:'dice')
I'm trying to notice when the player is clicking at the image, but it writing me that the rect of the dice is 0,0(x=0 and y=0), while the image is shown at 740,40.

what should I do?

```
bg = pygame.image.load("temptry.gif")
dice=pygame.image.load("dicee.gif")
screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
bg.blit(dice,(740,40))
pygame.display.update()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # Set the x, y postions of the mouse click
            x, y = event.pos
            print dice.get_rect()
            if dice.get_rect().collidepoint(x, y):
                print "omg"
    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    bg.blit(dice,(740,40))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: `dice.get_rect()` by default would make a pygame.Rect at (0, 0). Try using `dice.get_rect(left=740, top=40).collidepoint(x, y)` instead.

Comment: omg yess thank u so much!!!!! that's it!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code. Before the main loop you do not need `pygame.display.update()`. Next you should .convert() your images. For example dice = pygame.image.load("dicee.gif").convert() . Also there may be a problem with loading GIFS.

It seems like you are using very complicated ways of doing things. 
What I would suggest is that you have all the images loaded behind your main loop, convert the. After the main loop blit the image. Instead of doing `bg.blit(dice,(740,40))` how about you just do `screen.blit(bg,(740,40))`

Next you should make a mouse position variable after the main loop.

It should look like this

```
mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```

Next you should create rects for your dice image. Set a variable for it

dice_rect = dice.get_rect()

Then make an if statement that tests if someone clicks on the dice image

```
if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] and dice_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
      print "omg"
```

Then do `pygame.display.update()`

I hope this helped, if you have any further questions about this comment below.

Comment: I can't put both photos under the screen(screen.blit), it isn't working that way, I took the advice from that question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19336585/how-to-blit-an-image-in-python-inside-the-area-of-a-specific-image?rq=1

Comment: Also, I don't have problem loading the photos, they are shown to me on the right place at the screen, but the pygame just don't recognize they're right place

Comment: Im guessing you can blit the images fine then. Just use the collide point argument that tests if a person clicks on the image.

Comment: still say that is at (0,0)