# How do you make images in pygame and make them move?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, python-requests

I have been working on a game for a school project and I have these blocks come down the screen and you need to dodge them. I need to turn the blank drawn rectangles coming down the screen into a picture of a car I have.
This is my code so far:

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()

skate_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("skateboard.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.load("menu_audio.wav")
ouch = pygame.mixer.Sound("ouch.wav")



display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
cyan = (71, 148, 192)
green = (0, 255, 0)
dark_red = (200, 0 ,0)
dark_green = (0, 180 ,0)
grass_green = (39, 131, 51)
man_width = 35

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Skate or Die')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

manImg = pygame.image.load('skater1.png')





def objects_dodged(count):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    text = font.render("Dodged: "+str(count), True, black)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, (0,0))



def objects(objectx, objecty, objectw, objecth, color):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, color, [objectx, objecty, objectw, objecth])

#^^NEED TO CHANGE TO AN IMAGE CALLED TAXI.PNG CAN SOMEONE PLEASE FIX FOR ME    

def man(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(manImg,(x,y))

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()

    time.sleep(2)

    game_loop()


def crash():
    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(ouch)
    pygame.mixer.Sound.stop(skate_sound)
    message_display("You Died!")

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

        #print(click)
        if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
            pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic,(x,y,w,h))
            if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
                if action == "play":
                    game_loop()
                elif action == "quit":
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()

        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac,(x,y,w,h))

        smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",20)
        textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
        textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
        gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def game_intro():
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Skate or Die!", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button("Start",150,450,100,50,dark_green,green,"play")
        button("Quit",550,450,100,50,dark_red,red,"quit")



        #pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red,(550,450,100,50))

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(3)    



def game_loop():
    pygame.mixer.Sound.stop(ouch)
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(skate_sound)

    x = (display_width * 0.45)
    y = (display_height * 0.75)

    x_change = 0


    object_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
    object_starty = -600
    object_speed = 8
    object_width = 100
    object_height = 80 

    dodged = 0 


    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -5
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 5

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0

        x += x_change

        #gameDisplay.fill(white)
        bg = pygame.image.load("bg.png")
        gameDisplay.blit(bg, (0, 0))
        man(x,y)

        # objects(objectx, objecty, objectw, objecth, color)
        objects(object_startx, object_starty, object_width, object_height, cyan)
        object_starty += object_speed
        man(x,y)
        objects_dodged(dodged)



        if x > display_width - man_width or x < 0:
            crash()
        if object_starty > display_height:
            object_starty = 0 - object_height
            object_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
            dodged += 1
            object_speed += 0.7
            object_width += (dodged * 1)



        if y < object_starty+object_height:
            print('y crossover')

            if x > object_startx and x < object_startx + object_width or x+man_width > object_startx and x + man_width < object_startx+object_width:
                print('x crossover')
                crash()




        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)


game_intro()
game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

If someone could fix it so it displays taxi.png instead of the rectangles as objects it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19336585/how-to-blit-an-image-in-python-inside-the-area-of-a-specific-image

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to blit an image, in python, inside the area of a specific image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19336585/how-to-blit-an-image-in-python-inside-the-area-of-a-specific-image)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have an image appear in python/pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767129/how-to-have-an-image-appear-in-python-pygame)

Comment: You already have a movable image/pygame.Surface in your game, the `manImg`, so what's preventing you from doing the same with the blocks? It sounds like you haven't understood the tutorial that you're reading or watching, so reread it until you understand how the code works.

Answer (score 3):

To draw the picture of the car instead of a rectangle, just do the same thing that you are doing with the man.

Under the line that is `manImg = pygame.image.load('skater1.png')`, put this line: `carImg= pygame.image.load('taxi.png')` This will load the picture of the car and it will be called `carImg`.

Now, you need to draw that picture onto the screen. Replace your objects function:

```
def objects(objectx, objecty, objectw, objecth, color):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, color, [objectx, objecty, objectw, objecth])
```

with a function to draw a car.

```
def drawCar(x,y):
    pygameDisplay.blit(carImg,(x,y))
```

Notice how it is very similar to the `man` function, the only difference is the image that is drawn.

The last thing you need to do is actually call that `drawCar` function. Replace this line 
`objects(object_startx, object_starty, object_width, object_height, cyan)`

with this one: `drawCar(object_startx,object_starty)`

I would recommend doing these changes yourself, it will help you learn. But if you're in a hurry, the final code, with all of these changes made, should be:

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()

skate_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("skateboard.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.load("menu_audio.wav")
ouch = pygame.mixer.Sound("ouch.wav")



display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
cyan = (71, 148, 192)
green = (0, 255, 0)
dark_red = (200, 0 ,0)
dark_green = (0, 180 ,0)
grass_green = (39, 131, 51)
man_width = 35

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Skate or Die')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

manImg = pygame.image.load('skater1.png')
carImg= pygame.image.load('taxi.png')





def objects_dodged(count):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    text = font.render("Dodged: "+str(count), True, black)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, (0,0))



def drawCar(x,y):
    pygameDisplay.blit(carImg,(x,y))

def man(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(manImg,(x,y))

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()

    time.sleep(2)

    game_loop()


def crash():
    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(ouch)
    pygame.mixer.Sound.stop(skate_sound)
    message_display("You Died!")

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

        #print(click)
        if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
            pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic,(x,y,w,h))
            if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
                if action == "play":
                    game_loop()
                elif action == "quit":
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()

        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac,(x,y,w,h))

        smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",20)
        textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
        textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
        gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def game_intro():
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Skate or Die!", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button("Start",150,450,100,50,dark_green,green,"play")
        button("Quit",550,450,100,50,dark_red,red,"quit")



        #pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red,(550,450,100,50))

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(3)    



def game_loop():
    pygame.mixer.Sound.stop(ouch)
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(skate_sound)

    x = (display_width * 0.45)
    y = (display_height * 0.75)

    x_change = 0


    object_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
    object_starty = -600
    object_speed = 8
    object_width = 100
    object_height = 80 

    dodged = 0 


    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -5
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 5

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0

        x += x_change

        #gameDisplay.fill(white)
        bg = pygame.image.load("bg.png")
        gameDisplay.blit(bg, (0, 0))
        man(x,y)

        # objects(objectx, objecty, objectw, objecth, color)
        drawCar(object_startx,object_starty)
        object_starty += object_speed
        man(x,y)
        objects_dodged(dodged)
```

When you follow tutorials online, don't just copy and paste the code. Make sure that you understand what is happening so that in the future, you can do it yourself.

Comment: Thank you heaps, thats exactly what i needed!